# Python request with certificates error. Caused by SSLError(SSLError(9, '[SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:4027)

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, ssl-certificate, handshake

Here is my code:

```
import requests


url = 'https://ecomm.pashabank.az:18443/ecomm2/MerchantHandler'

headers = {'content-type' : 'application/json'}

data = { # some optional data
    "command": "v",
    "amount": "10",
    "currency": "932",
    "client_ip_addr": "167.992.139.153",
    "msg_type": "SMS"
}

# all certificates are in the current directory within this script file
psroot = "PSroot.pem"
cert_file = "certificate.0025598.der"
key_file = "certificate.0025598.pem"

certs = (cert_file, key_file, psroot)
response = requests.post(url, cert=certs)
```

raises this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mammadaliyevmammadali/Desktop/bank/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    response = requests.post(url, cert=certs)
  File "/Users/mammadaliyevmammadali/.local/share/virtualenvs/bank-wIDLHQju/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 115, in post
    return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mammadaliyevmammadali/.local/share/virtualenvs/bank-wIDLHQju/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mammadaliyevmammadali/.local/share/virtualenvs/bank-wIDLHQju/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/mammadaliyevmammadali/.local/share/virtualenvs/bank-wIDLHQju/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mammadaliyevmammadali/.local/share/virtualenvs/bank-wIDLHQju/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 563, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ecomm.pashabank.az', port=18443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ecomm2/MerchantHandler (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(9, '[SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:4027)')))
```

Pay attention to **_ssl.c:4027** at the end of error. I couldn't find out how to fix this. I need to verify my 3 certificates proceeding the request. How to do that? All certificates are correctly formed and passed for security. All implementations are correct, but my script doesn't work. Please help!

Comment: *...All certificates are correctly formed and passed for security...* **None** of the certificates are any good. Both use 1024 bit RSA keys, too short to be considered secure in 2023. The server certificate is X509 version 1! It has no hostname in the common name and (of course none in the subject alt name extension because there are no extensions in an X509v1 certificate). I wouldn't be surprised if there were other problems in those certificates.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk all certificates are trusted and correctly imported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> cert_file = "certificate.0025598.der"
> ```

Given the file extension this looks like a DER formatted certificate to me. But a PEM formatted is expected. Certificates can be converted from DER to PEM with

```
 openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.0025598.der -out certificate.0025598.pem
```

And then use `certificate.0025598.pem` instead.

> .... Caused by SSLError(SSLError(9, '[SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:4027)')))

This error refers to the line 4027 in Modules/_ssl.c in the source code, but without having your exact Python version it is not known what code is at this line number. All what is known is that your are using some sort of Python 3.9. A relevant code near this line number [is this though](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Modules/_ssl.c#L4031):

```
  4031      r = SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(self->ctx,
  4032          PyBytes_AS_STRING(certfile_bytes));
  4033      PySSL_END_ALLOW_THREADS_S(pw_info.thread_state);
  4034      if (r != 1) {
  ...
  4044              _setSSLError(NULL, 0, __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

This is the code which tries to load the certificate given as client certificate, i.e. your `certificate.0025598.der`. `PEM lib` means that the error comes from a part in OpenSSL which tried to interpret the certificate as PEM - and failed. Thus it matches what I've speculated initially, i.e. that your certificate is not in the expected PEM format but in DER format.

Comment: any difference between .der and .DER?

Comment: @Docker: File extensions are only an indicator what the file content __might__ be, not what the file content actually __must__ be. My guess is that the file is in DER format since it has the extension .der. The guess would be the same if the file extension were .DER since extensions are typically treated as case-insentive.

Comment: Oh, okay. thanks! yeah my .der file is that .DER-extensioned file