# Python, how to send a request with attached certificates?

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, ssl-certificate

I have 3 files/certificates:

[image]

I need to send a POST request to the bank attaching all these 3 certificates to these `url`:

[image]

This is my code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://ecomm.pashabank.az:18443/ecomm2/MerchantHandler'

data = { # for example
    "command": "v",
    "amount": "1",
    "currency": "932",
    "client_ip_addr": "167.172.184.123",
    "msg_type": "SMS"
}

cert_file = "certificate.0025598.der"
key_file = "certificate.0025598.pem"
psroot = "PSroot.pem"
certs = (cert_file, key_file, psroot)
response = requests.post(url, cert=certs)
```

But it doesn't work, giving this error:

```
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ecomm.pashabank.az', port=18443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ecomm2/MerchantHandler (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(9, '[SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:4027)')))
```

Maybe I am attaching certificates incorrectly? Please help!

I wanted to send the request via Postman, but I also failed there. Could you explain how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75140285/python-request-with-certificates-error-caused-by-sslerrorsslerror9-ssl-pe

Comment: Didn't work, the same person ask this

Comment: It is unclear what the contents of cert_file, key_file and psroot is. You need the certificate and the private key to this - and none of the names you use suggests that any of the files is the private key

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure your cert is format in pem.
2. pass the filename to param `cert` (or file path, which means your pem file is in current directory)

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/?highlight=cert#client-side-certificates

Comment: According to the bank, I need to send those 3 files throught the request. What you mean by first point?

Comment: I guess your cert files are not in pem format which may not be supported by the requests, you can google "der to pem".